# Two Facebook apps for the same website?

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph, facebook-sharer

I have a web app in which users can have a variety of activities and I want them to be able to share them on Facebook using *custom* Open Graph stories.

There are also public pages and I want my users to be able to share those pages on Facebook using the share dialog (including those who did not use the Facebook login).

Those two kinds of sharing are incompatible in a single Facebook app:

> publish_actions is only for custom-built sharing experiences. If your app triggers a Facebook dialog to share, you won't be approved for publish_actions

Would it make sense in this case to create two Facebook apps? If not, what is the recommended way to handle this?

Comment: side note: custom og stories are deprecated. you know that, right?

Comment: why not just use the share dialog? no user authorization needed.

Comment: _" what is the recommended way to handle this?"_ - one app, and proper explanation in app review as to why you need this permission. If you are using the API to share, then this is a legitimate use case. It doesn't matter that you use the dialog for something else in a different scenario.